# type error cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux

this is the function I declared

```
const Cart = () => {
    const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
```

this is some of the codes within the function:

```
                <Info>
                    {cart.products.map((product)=> (
                    <Product>
                        <ProductDetail>                                
                            <Image src={product.img}/>
                            <Details>
                                <ProductName>
                                    <b>Product :</b>{product.title}
                                </ProductName>
                                <ProductSize>
                                    <b>Size :</b>{product.size}
                                </ProductSize>
                            </Details>
                        </ProductDetail>
                        <PriceDetails>
                            <ProductAmountContainer>
                                <Remove/>
                                <ProductAmount>
                                    {product.inStock}
                                </ProductAmount>
                                <Add/>
                            </ProductAmountContainer>
                            <ProductPrice> 
                                <b>RM </b>{product.price*product.quantity}
                            </ProductPrice>
                        </PriceDetails>
                    </Product>
                    ))}
                    <Hr/>
                </Info>
```

However , I am getting these two errors in my browser.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'img')

155 | {cart.products.map((product)=> (
156 | <Product>
157 |     <ProductDetail>                                
>158|         <Image src={product.img}/>
|159| ^        <Details>
160 |             <ProductName>
161 |                 <b>Product :</b>{product.title}
```

Another error:

```
Cart
 C:/Users/timot/OneDrive/Desktop/html css 
 projects/OmazonShop/frontend/src/pages/Cart.jsx:154
   151 |     <TopButton type = "filled">CHECKOUT NOW</TopButton>
  152 | </Top>
  153 | <Bottom>
> 154 |     <Info>
  | ^  155 |         {cart.products.map((product)=> (
  156 |         <Product>
  157 |             <ProductDetail>
```

> I am a bit puzzled because my product.title is working just fine.

Comment: I may miss posting some files , feel free to tell me in the comment

Comment: that's why you posted here: no need to comment with that. The error is telling you that `product` is nothing, so: figure out why. Where are you getting it, what's setting it, and at what point in the lifetime of that thing does it stop containing what it should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return the Product Component if `cart.products` is available. You can use optional chaining or check if the products is available then return the Product otherwise return loading or any other text.